# How to create a Firestore schema for a music app?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Cloud Firestore database for music:

```
ROOT
 |
 +-- shops {collection}
      |
      +-- countryName {document}
             |
             +-- cityName {collection}
                   |
                   +-- shopIdOne {document}
                         |
                         +-- dvds {collection}
                              |
                              +-- dvdIdOne {document}
                              |     |
                              |     +-- name: "Led Zeppelin: Live in Seattle 1977"
                              |
                              +-- dvdIdTwo {document}
                                    |
                                    +-- name: "Queen: Live at AID 1985"
```

Using this schema I can get all music dvds from a shop in an existing city, which is fine. The problem is that the same dvd can exist in at least 5 shops in different cities.

I know I cannot query on multiple collections, so the question is, how to create a schema so I can query the database by dvd name and get all the shops where it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: As of May, 2019, Cloud Firestore now supports [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).**

With a collection group query, you can query all `dvds` collections across all shops:

```
db.collectionGroup('dvds').where('name', '==', 'Led Zeppelin: Live in Seattle 1977')
```

**Original Answer**

If you want to be able to find the shops that have a specific DVD, you will have to store that precise information in the database too. So:

```
ROOT
 |
 +-- DVDs {collection}
      |
      +-- dvdIdOne {document}
      |     |
      |     +-- name: "Led Zeppelin: Live in Seattle 1977"
      |      |
      |      +-- shops {collection}
      |            |
      |            +-- shopIdOne {document}
      |
      +-- dvdIdTwo {document}
            |
            +-- name: "Queen: Live at AID 1985"      |
             |
             +-- shops {collection}
                   |
                   +-- shopIdOne {document}
```

Either that, or you can wait for collection group queries to become available (no timeline is known for that at the moment though) and see if the allow the use-case on the current data structure.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering me. For the moment I'll go with this solution but the collection group queries will do miracles, can't wait to be released.